# When I try to play with ListNode, a error of 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' occurs

Tags: java, linked-list, out-of-memory

I wrote a main method for a small demo of ListNode. However, it showed a strange error of 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space';

The ListNode class is:

```
static class ListNode extends Object {
        int val;
        ListNode next;

        ListNode() {

        }

        ListNode(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public String toString(){
            StringBuffer value = new StringBuffer();
            value.append(this.val);
            while(next != null){
                value.append(next.val);
                next = next.next;
            }
            return value.toString();
        }
    }
```

and I wrote a method for add two numbers of values of ListNod:

```
public static ListNode addTwoNums(ListNode l1, ListNode l2){
        ListNode resultLN = new ListNode();

        StringBuffer lString = new StringBuffer().append(l1.val);
        ListNode lNext = l1.next;
        while (lNext != null){
            lString.append(lNext.val);
            lNext = lNext.next;
        }
        Integer l1Int = Integer.parseInt(lString.toString());
        System.out.println("l1Int: " + l1Int);

        lString = new StringBuffer().append(l2.val);
        lNext = l2.next;
        while (lNext != null){
            lString.append(lNext.val);
            lNext = lNext.next;
        }
        Integer l2Int = Integer.parseInt(lString.toString());
        System.out.println("l2Int: " + l2Int);

        Integer total = l1Int + l2Int;
        System.out.println("total: " + total);

        System.out.println("Starting ============ ");
        String resultString = new StringBuffer().append(total).reverse().toString();
                System.out.println("Reversed: " + resultString);
        int i = 0;
        ListNode node = new ListNode();
        resultLN.next = null;
        while(i < resultString.length()){
            resultLN.val = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(resultString.charAt(i)));
            resultLN.next = resultLN;
            i ++;
        }
        return resultLN;
    }
```

The main method is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(2, new ListNode(4, new ListNode(3)));
        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(5, new ListNode(6, new ListNode(4)));
        ListNode resultListNode = addTwoNums(l1,l2);
        System.out.println(resultListNode.toString());
    }
```

The printed result like:

```
l1Int: 243
l2Int: 564
total: 807
Starting ============ 
Reversed: 708
```

However, the last print doesn't show. I'm expecting the result like '708' in the last line of main method, but I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
```

Does anybody know what's the problem of my demo ? Is there any problem of my last 'while' loop?

Comment: What's strange about it? You're out of memory.

Comment: `resultLN.next = resultLN;` - you make your node point to itself as the next one - so that means your `toString` method will loop endlessly

Comment: "result like" are you getting that result or are you expecting that result? Please don't use 'like' in that kind of sentences.  Same for "I'm expecting the result like '708'". Are you expecting the result to be exactly 708, or do you expect it to be similar to 708? Please be more precise.

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Comment: Thanks mate! You are correct, I was wrong with creating the ListNode. @UnholySheep